# Checking if sentence contains a word in PHP

Tags: php

How can I check if a sentence contains a word. I used names sentence and word instead of string and substring expressly. For example:
for sentence

```
$s = "Ala makota, a kot ma przesrane";
```

calling function

```
checkIfContains("kota",$s)
```

returns false.

But for

```
checkIfContains("makota",$s)
```

returns true.

Comment: please read the php manual for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or better yer, read the whole chapter named [String functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: @VladBalmos it is not only about if string simply contains substring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking to match only full words, you'll need a regular expression to accomplish this. Try the following:

```
<?php
function checkIfContains( $needle, $haystack ) {
    return preg_match( '#\b' . preg_quote( $needle, '#' ) . '\b#i', $haystack ) !== 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @BerryLangerak, it works:) but you forgot the second argument of preg_match function which is $haystack

Comment: @Martin So I did. Well, can't test everything you post ;)

Comment: Caution: default delimiter char is '/' not '#'. Just replace '#' by '/' to get this example working correctly.

Comment: @AdrianMaire A bit late, but here goes: yes, the "normal" delimiter is "/". In a web context however, I found this to be *very* cumbersome, so I started looking for a better one. I finally ended up with "~", because that's not used a lot.

Anyway, the example is valid with `#` as well as `/`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if (strpos($s, 'kota') !== false) { 

}
```

Or if you insist..

```
function checkIfContains($needle, $haystack) {
    return (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false);
}
```

For full words you could consider regex:

```
if (preg_match('/\bkota\b/i', $s)) { }
```

Comment: Actually, no, he's looking for *full* words, which means strpos isn't enough.

Comment: `checkIfContains("Ala makota" "kota")` should be false, according to his question. Your function will return true.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use explode to separate the string into an array based on a character (" " in this case).

```
function checkIfContains($toTest, $toCheck)
{
    // Check if length of either string is zero for validation purposes
    if(strlen($toTest) == 0 || strlen($toCheck) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $exploded = explode(" ", $toCheck);
    foreach($exploded as $word)
    {
         if($word == $toTest)
         {
              // Found a match, return true!
              return true;
         }
    }
    // None matched, return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Then what if the sentence is "foo bar kota." Still contains "kota", as a word, but since your script sees "kota." instead, it won't work. That's why I opted for using `\b` (word boundary) in a regex.

Comment: Also, you could've used `in_array( $word, $exploded )` instead of the slower foreach. So: `$exploded = explode( " ", $toCheck ); return in_array( $toTest, $exploded );`

Comment: First comment: good point, although I'm curious if you want to look for words with non-word characters in the middle (such as "8:00")

Second comment: I could have (and in_array is certainly quicker). My reasoning for expanding it out was to make it clearer what's happening, assuming that the asker is relatively new.

Comment: `checkIfContains("8:00", "I woke up at 8:00") === true && checkIfContains("8:00", "I woke up at 18:00") === false`, so exactly what the asker asked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
function checkIfContains($needle, $haystack) {
    // Remove punctuation marks
    $haystack = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/', '', $haystack);
    // Explode sentence with space
    $haystack = explode(' ', $haystack);
    // Check if $needle exist
    return in_array($needle, $haystack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Ala makota, a kot ma przesrane";

checkIfInString("makota", $string);

function checkIfInString($needle, $haystack) {
    $delimiters = ' ,.';
    return in_array($needle, explode($haystack, $delimiters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like :

```php
if(strpos($s,"kota") !== false){
       echo true;
}
```

or :

```php
function checkIfContains($string, $letter){
       return strpos($string, $letter) !== false;
}
```